# Share gitlab.com runner cache with self-hosted gitlab-runner

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I currently have set up a GitLab CI/CD pipeline with jobs that use the `cache` feature to share data between jobs. I recently purchased a Mac mini and installed gitlab-runner. I changed one of the jobs in my pipeline to run locally on the Mac mini and I get the following error when running the job:

`No URL provided, cache will not be downloaded from shared cache server. Instead a local version of cache will be extracted.`

I want the job running locally on the Mac mini to still use the cache that is being saved from jobs running on gitlab.com runners. How do I configure my gitlab-runner to do this?